# Google Places API - Place ID refresh

Tags: google-search, website-review, google-api

How often is the data refreshed for the Google Places API for a newly created organization? Put another way long does it take for a newly registered business to populate in the search?

The organization I'm trying to create a review link for isn't available.

https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJC-XORTkRkFQRHs_yokwHiho

The organization is available in search though:
https://www.google.com/search?ludocid=819605522386240925&hl=en&q=Stack%20%26%20Tier%2013517%20Meridian%20Ave%20N%20Seattle%2C%20WA%2098133&_ga=1.219520798.623038704.1489768071

Answer (score 1):

Approximately a week and a half.

https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJC-XORTkRkFQRncXHUeHSXws